# Gson "toJson" function crash (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android

When i'm converting an ArrayList to String using Gson library, my app crash. However, it only crash on my smartphone (lg g5, Android 7.0), but not on the Android Studio Emulator (Nexus 6, Android 9).

Is it that Gson isn't compatible with Android 7.0 ?

I've tried with older versions of Gson.

**This is in an activity**

```
ArrayList<Character> mCharacters = new ArrayList<>();
private SharedPreferences mPreferences;
mPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);


private void saveGame(){
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(mCharacters); //crash here
    mPreferences.edit().putString("characters", json).apply();
}


@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    saveGame();
}
```

**Here is my character java class**

```
public class Character {
    private String mName;
    private boolean mGirl;
    private Drawable mPicture;

    public Character(String name, boolean girl, Drawable picture) {
        mName = name;
        mGirl = girl;
        mPicture = picture;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return mName;
    }

    public boolean isGirl() {
        return mGirl;
    }

    public Drawable getPicture() {
        return mPicture;
    }


}
```

My mCharacters have 2 characters in it before it crash.

I don't get any error messages, but my screen freeze and the debugger say that the app still run.

Comment: See this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50081231/serialize-object-that-contains-a-drawable-android-java

Answer (score 0):

`Drawable` cannot be converted to a json object. So your application is crashing.

You should convert your drawable image into bitmap and store in file storage and use the file path instead of Drawable object.

If your drawable image is referenced from the `res/drawable` then you can also use int value (`R.drawable.image_name`) and use that int value instead of Drawable object.